# d3-driven directive transition doesn't work inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, transition

I am trying to include my d3 code inside a directive.

However, when my directive is inside a ng-repeat, the transitions won't take place.

Here's a JSFiddle of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/hLtweg8L/1/ : You can see that when you click on the button, the rectangles position doesn't change smoothly, and `'append'` is logged to the console once again.

My directive is the following:

```
myMod.directive('chart',function(){
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    scope:{
      data:'=',
    },
      link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
          a=d3.select(elem[0]);
          rects=a.selectAll("rect").data(scope.data,function(d));

          rects.enter().append("rect")
             .attr("x",function(d,i){console.log('append');return i*50+"px"})
             .attr("y",100)
             .attr("width",35)
             .attr("height",function(d){return d.age*10+"px"})
             .attr("fill","blue")

          rects.transition().duration(200)
             .attr("x",function(d,i){console.log('append');return i*50+"px"})
             .attr("y",100)
             .attr("width",35)
             .attr("height",function(d){return d.age*10+"px"})
             .attr("fill","blue")
    }
  }
})
```

As far as I understand it, the problem is that the `elem` passed inside the link function is not the same when the ng-repeat gets updated, that's why the append gets called more than once for the same data.

My question is: How can I use d3 transitions inside ng-repeat ? (Corrected Jsfiddle would help a lot). Or why is the elem not the same between different calls ? Can I tell angular that the dom shouldn't be removed and added again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things are needed:

- If you don't want ng-repeat to create a new element, you need to use the `track by` option so that it knows how to identify new vs. changed items:

  `<div ng-repeat="set in sets track by set.group">`
- D3 will not automatically see that the data has changed unless your directive watches for changes.

  ```
    a=d3.select(elem[0]);
    scope.$watch('data', function() {
        updateGraph();
    });
  ```

Here is an an alternate Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/63tze4Lv/1/